# WPF ContentControl content not getting parent Resources

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently getting to grips with WPF resources and wondering if you can help me:

I have a WPF window which contains its own resources. It also contains a content control which changes its content depending on what is selected in a tree view, e.g.:

```
contentControl1.Content = someUserControl;
```

This can be a UserControl e.g. `SomeUserControl` which uses a static resource which I have defined in the window xaml.

When creating an instance of `SomeUserControl` in the window code behind, I get an XMLParseException ('Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.'). This is on the line containing the binding to the static resource.

To solve this, I added this to the constructor of SomeUserControl (parentResources being the window's resources from where someUserControl is instantiated):

```
public SomeUserControl(ResourceDictionary parentResources)
{
    this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(parentResources);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Is this the best approach for finding resources in this particular case? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a `{StaticResource myResource}`.  Have you tried using `{DynamicResource myResource}`?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942.aspx

**EDIT**

Ok, given that you're resource is a converter, which cannot use a dynamic resource, then I think what you're doing is probably as a good a solution as any.

The underlying issue is that at the moment that your control is instantiated, it is not a part of the Window and so it doesn't have any access to the Window's resources.  And as the term static in `StaticResource` implies, the control expects that the resource is going to be available.  So you have to make it available when the control is instantiated.

You might also want to look at something like [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) and it's Region's which might be a better way to handle swapping out your "controls" (depending on your needs).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion: No, this does not help, instead I get: A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'Converter' property of type 'Binding'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject. - I'm currently binding to a Convertor I have written

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what resource you're talking about, actually.

Cause the way you do it could be pretty fine, with only drawback, that you detach yourself from declarative programming, which is *expected* way of coding in WPF.

You can also add a `StaticResource`, for example in App.xaml, so it will be initialized *and* loaded as soon as your app starts, and in any way, *before* window load.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am binding to a Convertor I have written. Unfortunately I can't add to the App.xaml; I'm hosting a WPF form in winforms. There are workarounds (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799515/adding-a-static-resourcedictionary-to-usercontrols-before-the-xaml-is-parsed) but I am using the top level window's resources as the app.xaml equivalent and not displaying any other wpf forms which could potentially share resources.

Comment: Considering, kind of extreme conditions (hosting in WinForms) don't see any problem in what you're doing now, so.